# Solr Java Index Searching

Tags: mysql, spring, solr

I'm new to Solr , actually I'm trying search data from mysql using Solr Index Search method, when I search single data, it's shows multiple data related to the Index,

for eg:

Company table:-

```
Id  company_name    company_id  company_emp
1      Xx               1              Xx
2      yy               2              Yy
```

empDetail:-

```
Id  company_id  company_empA    emp_city    emp_mobile
1      1               dd              ss       32455
2      1               cc              cc       344444
3      1               zz              zz       56778998
```

Here I have used `OneToMany` relationship between Company table and Employee Detail Table, When I search `ss` from `emp_City` , it's gives all data which is related to `Company_id` instead of only `ss`

Current result show like this

```
id  company_id  company_name    company_empA    emp_city
1      1           Xx             dd              ss
2      1           Xx             cc              cc
3      1           Xx             zz              zz
```

the above result shows all the `emp_city` value which is related to the `Company_id`. but I want to get only `ss`.

I have configured `Data-config.xml`  Solr configuration file as follow

```
<document name="company1">
    <entity name="companys" pk="id" query="SELECT * FROM company"  deltaImportQuery="select * from company where id='${dataimporter.delta.id}'" >
        <field column="company_id" name="id" />
        <field column=" company_name " name=" company_name " />
        <field column=" company_emp " name=" company_emp " />
        <field column="company_id" name="companyId"/>


<entity name="companyDetails" pk="id " query="select * from company_detail where company_id='${companys.company_id}' ORDER BY '${companys.company_id}'" 
             parentDeltaQuery="select id from company_detail where company_id=${companys.company_id}">
        <field column="company_id" name="id"/>
            <field column="company_id" name="com_companyId"/>
            <field column="company_empA" name="com_companyemp"/>
                <field column=" emp_city " name=" emp_city" />
                <field column=" emp_mobile " name=" emp_mobile "/>
            </entity>
</entity>
```

I think the problem is in this Query, but I couldn't find it out, kindly help me to resolve it. thanks in advance.

Comment: can you include how you query "ss"

Comment: @kali I have already mentioned query here in configuration file.

Comment: @RathaKrishna, just to verify, the examples you have provided, are they sample datA from the ordinal values you have in your database?

Comment: @JtheRocker Yes.. it's gave the actual ordinal values from database..